# Can I extract all indices that correspond to a certain key in a pytorch tensor?

Tags: python, pytorch, indices

Say I have a pytorch tensor `tensor([3,5,7,3,9,3,0])`. I'd like to extract the indices where `3` appears, i.e. `tensor([0,3,5])`. Is there a built-in function for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a dedicated [function](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.where) for this:

```
   torch.where(my_tensor == the_number)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
t = torch.Tensor([1, 2, 3 , 2 , 5])
print ((t == 2).nonzero())
```

nonzero prints all non zero location of a torch tensor
https://pytorch.org/docs/master/generated/torch.nonzero.html